# Where is the "Software Center"?

Tags: software-center, 20.04

Forgive me, I am a ubuntu-newb.

I was running UbuntuStudio 19.10, and upgraded to 20.04.  I want to look through the software repository, but can't find the "Software Center" discussed here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/FindingSoftware.  I think I used it once before, because I have Rosegarden running - but now I can't find it.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 it's called "Ubuntu Software" Note that your link is 8 years old and quite stale.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has 'Ubuntu Software' been renamed to 'Snap Store'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252134/has-ubuntu-software-been-renamed-to-snap-store)

Answer (score 3):

The package you are looking for is called `gnome-software` (formerly called `ubuntu-software`).

When you install it, it will automatically install `snapd`. But you can remove it afterwards if you don't need it.