# Anyone else lost Software Manager after the recent ubuntu-base update?

Tags: updates, printing, software-center, update-manager, cups-lpd

Yesterday Software Updater reported that there were a few updates to install (64Mb worth) which I set running. However, after a reboot, I'd lost my CUPS drivers + Software Manager. The first was easy to sort out - I went to the HP site, downloaded and ran the HPLIP installer to install new drivers. However, the second I have no idea about. Software Manager was on my taskbar but disappeared and is no longer shown in the list of available app's. Any ideas anyone please ?

Comment: Are you talking about Ubuntu? Which release and flavor? I've never a "Software Manager" placed "on my taskbar" in any Ubuntu release, so just checking.

Comment: The details of the "recent ubuntu-base" release, including the exact packages that were upgraded, is in /var/log/apt. Logs of your specific upgrade would be key to helping you, since normal upgrades don't delete software.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has 'Ubuntu Software' been renamed to 'Snap Store'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252134/has-ubuntu-software-been-renamed-to-snap-store)

Answer (score 0):

Try
`sudo apt install gnome-software`
then typing  "software" in "activities" should find it .
I just saw there is already a better answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252134/has-ubuntu-software-been-renamed-to-snap-store)