# It's mentioned in the logs that "Settings schema 'org.gnome.software' is not installed"

Tags: log, gnome-software

It's mentioned in the logs that

> Settings schema 'org.gnome.software' is not installed

[image: Logs screenshot]

I was kinda confused/worried after reading this log because it was under 'Important' category and comes under 'Security'. Why is it under 'Important' category and comes under 'Security'?
So I decided to install [`gnome-software`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gnome-software) using the command `sudo apt install gnome-software`. Did I do the right thing?

I found out that whenever I launch Snap Store from the `gnome-software` app, [image: Snap Store app in gnome-software app] the log mentioning

> Settings schema 'org.gnome.software' is not installed

appears again.

One more thing to note is that the Ubuntu Software app [image] doesn't open. I executed `apt list --installed | grep ubuntu-software` command and the output was:

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
```

So it looks like the Ubuntu Software app is not installed but it's still shown in the applications. Does this have any connection with the log? I'm clueless, please explain what the exact issue is over here.

Output of `apt policy ubuntu-software`:

```
ubuntu-software:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0
  Version table:
     3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
     3.36.0-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
```

Output of `apt policy ubuntu-software | grep Installed`:

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

  Installed: (none)
```

Output of `snap-store`:

```
11:06:47:0922 Gtk Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
11:06:47:0927 Gtk Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
11:06:47:0936 GLib-GIO Settings schema 'org.gnome.software' is not installed
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Output of `snap list`:

```
Name               Version                      Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
core               16-2.47                      10126  latest/stable    canonical✓  core
core18             20200724                     1885   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-28-1804    3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67   145    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-3-34-1804    0+git.3556cb3                60     latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes  0.1-36-gc75f853              1506   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
inkscape           1.0.1-3bc2e813f5-2020-09-07  7947   latest/stable    inkscape✓   -
pycharm-community  2020.2.3                     214    latest/stable    jetbrains✓  classic
snap-store         3.36.0-82-g80486d0           481    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snapd              2.46.1                       9279   latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
vlc                3.0.11                       1700   latest/stable    videolan✓   -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snap-store` was installed in the PC but there was no app in the "Show Applications" named Snap Store.

I uninstalled `snap-store` using the command:

```
sudo snap remove snap-store
```

After uninstalling `snap-store`, the Ubuntu Software icon [image] disappeared.

Then I installed `snap-store` using the command:

```
sudo snap install snap-store
```

Then the Snap Store app was shown in the "Show Applications".

[image: Snap Store app icon]

Now there is no log mentioning

> Settings schema 'org.gnome.software' is not installed

---

So looks like there was some issue with the Snap Store app, but I don't have any idea what caused the issue since I didn't mess with anything in regards to `snap-store`.

One more detail to note is that the output of `snap list` has changed a bit after uninstalling and installing `snap-store`. The output of `snap list`:

```
Name               Version                      Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
core               16-2.47                      10126  latest/stable    canonical✓  core
core18             20200724                     1885   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-28-1804    3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67   145    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-3-34-1804    0+git.3556cb3                60     latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes  0.1-36-gc75f853              1506   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
inkscape           1.0.1-3bc2e813f5-2020-09-07  7947   latest/stable    inkscape✓   -
pycharm-community  2020.2.3                     214    latest/stable    jetbrains✓  classic
snap-store         3.31.1+git187.84b64e0b       415    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
snapd              2.46.1                       9279   latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
vlc                3.0.11                       1700   latest/stable    videolan✓   -
```

The version of `snap-store` before uninstalling it was `3.36.0-82-g80486d0` (beta version). The version of `snap-store` after installing it again is `3.31.1+git187.84b64e0b` (stable version).

[image: Snap Store website screenshot]
Screenshot taken (on 13th October, 2020) from https://snapcraft.io/snap-store

---

**Update**:
After couple of days, the Snap Store icon went missing and Ubuntu Software icon was back. I *guess* this happened mostly after some updates.

When I execute `snap-store` command in terminal, the Ubuntu Software app opens. So I *guess* Snap Store is just rebranded as Ubuntu Software.

One more thing to note is the output of `snap list`.

```
Name               Version                      Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
core               16-2.47.1                    10185  latest/stable    canonical✓  core
core18             20200724                     1885   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-28-1804    3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67   145    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-3-34-1804    0+git.3556cb3                60     latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes  0.1-36-gc75f853              1506   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
inkscape           1.0.1-0767f8302a-2020-10-17  8049   latest/stable    inkscape✓   -
pycharm-community  2020.2.3                     214    latest/stable    jetbrains✓  classic
snap-store         3.36.0-82-g80486d0           481    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
snapd              2.47.1                       9721   latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
```

The version of `snap-store` now is `3.36.0-82-g80486d0`.

[image: Snap Store website screenshot as on 23rd October 2020]
Screenshot taken (on 23rd October,2020) from https://snapcraft.io/snap-store

But the weird thing is, most of the channels (stable, beta and candidate) have the same version number in the website. But since I didn't mess up with any `snap-store` stuff, I hope I'm in stable channel.

Output of `snap info snap-store`:

```
name:    snap-store
summary: Snap Store is a graphical desktop application for discovering, installing and managing
  snaps on Linux.
publisher: Canonical✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/snap-store
contact:   https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store/
license:   unset
description: |
  Snap Store showcases featured and popular applications with useful descriptions, ratings, reviews
  and screenshots.
  
  
  Applications can be found either through browsing categories
  or by searching.
  
  
  Snap Store can also be used to switch channels, view and alter snap permissions and view and
  submit reviews and ratings.
  
  
  Snap Store is based on GNOME Software, optimized for the Snap experience.
commands:
  - snap-store
  - snap-store.ubuntu-software
  - snap-store.ubuntu-software-local-file
snap-id:      gjf3IPXoRiipCu9K0kVu52f0H56fIksg
tracking:     latest/stable
refresh-date: 3 days ago, at 06:55 IST
channels:
  latest/stable:    3.36.0-82-g80486d0 2020-10-19 (481) 53MB -
  latest/candidate: 3.36.0-82-g80486d0 2020-10-19 (481) 53MB -
  latest/beta:      3.36.0-82-g80486d0 2020-09-11 (481) 53MB -
  latest/edge:      20200414.ac9047f   2020-04-14 (375) 50MB -
installed:          3.36.0-82-g80486d0            (481) 53MB -
```

Answer (score 2):

You did the right thing.

The `ubuntu-software` command returns the following result if the ubuntu-software package is installed in Ubuntu 20.04:

```
ubuntu-software: command not found
```

The `gnome-software` command launches the Software app.

The Snap Store app [image] is another software center app for snap packages only.

The Snap Store app can be installed alongside the Software app [image] in Ubuntu 20.04 with the following command:

```
sudo snap install snap-store
```

When I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 the Snap Store which was installed in Ubuntu 18.04 was removed from Ubuntu 20.04. When I noticed that the Snap Store was missing I reinstalled it, and since then it has worked with no problems.

Comment: But why is the Ubuntu Software icon shown in the "Show Applications" and dock, if it's not installed?

Comment: I think it has something to do with this question about Ubuntu 20.04: [Has 'Ubuntu Software' been renamed to 'Snap Store'?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1252134/), especially the accepted answer to it.

Comment: I've added one more detail to my question. Please check.

Comment: My Ubuntu 20.04 was upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 after the 20.04.1 point release was launched in August, 2020. The old orange Ubuntu Software icon from 18.04 was removed from the Dash by the release upgrade and replaced by the new blue Software icon.

Comment: Oh.. but in my case nothing like that happened. If I remember properly, couple of days ago the Ubuntu Software app went missing and new app named Snap Store was installed and I was able to open the Snap Store app. Then after an update, the Snap Store app went missing and the Ubuntu Software icon came back, but I couldn't open the Ubuntu Software app.

Comment: I replied to the last comment by editing my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115061/discussion-between-technastic-tc-and-karel).