# How to remove Ubuntu Software?

Tags: package-management, software-center, gnome-software

Im using Ubuntu 20.04. Some time ago, the gnome software app had disappeared, so I reinstalled it using `apt-get install gnome-software`

Now after a recent update, I'm seeing two software applications, one named 'Software' which was there before, and another named 'Ubuntu Software.' I checked the package list, but I see no new packages.

Some other answers say that the second one is 'ubuntu-software-center' but that is not the case, I checked.

Moreover, I tried uninstalling 'gnome-software', and the old one I installed, i.e. 'Software' goes away, and the new one stays. However, when I right click an application, I no longer have the option to view the details of that application.

I want to get rid of the new 'Ubuntu Software.' But I cannot find its package name. Does anybody know what it is and how do I remove it?

Comment: Do they launch the same application?  Maybe you have more than one desktop file in `/usr/share/applications`. I would not recommend attempting to remove the GUI package manager

Comment: Try this command: `snap remove snap-store`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap remove snap-store
```

When you right-click an application's icon and select Show Details, the Software app opens and shows details about that app. Of course in order to open the Software app it must be installed.

There are two different software apps in Ubuntu 20.04, Software [image] and Snap Store [image]. The Snap Store was originally named Ubuntu Software before the first point release of Ubuntu 20.04 was released. Now it is named the Snap Store and as its name suggests it has only snap packages in it. The Software app has both snap and .deb software in it. The Snap Store and the Software app can be installed alongside each other without removing either app.

If the app with the orange shopping bag icon that was named Ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 18.04 got removed in 20.04 it can be reinstalled by running `sudo apt install gnome-software`.  My Ubuntu 20.04 was upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04. The old Ubuntu Software app's name was changed to Software by the upgrade and the color of the app's shopping bag icon changed from orange to light blue. Even though the name of the app has changed, the name of the app's package is still gnome-software. In Ubuntu 22.04 and later the Software app's name has been changed back to Ubuntu Software and clicking the orange shopping bag Ubuntu Software icon launches the Snap Store instead.

Ubuntu Software icon in Ubuntu 22.04: [image]

Comment: Do read this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1283428/1103140

Comment: @technastic_tc That's the one. That orange shopping bag used to be the Ubuntu Software icon when Ubuntu 20.04 was released in April, 2020. It got changed to the current Software app icon by a software update. Now the Software app icon looks soft looking and the Snap Store icon looks like a shopping bag with a snappy bird on it.

Comment: Snap Store has been rebranded as Ubuntu Software..

Comment: My Ubuntu 20.04 was upgraded from 18.04. After the upgrade completed I noticed that the Snap Store had been uninstalled by the upgrade, so I reinstalled it. It's still named the Snap Store in my Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: hmm.. what's the version of Snap Store?

Comment: latest/stable: 3.36.0-82

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115490/discussion-between-technastic-tc-and-karel).

Comment: What a muddled mess these software apps are. +1 for a clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 upgraded from 18.04
Had same issue; Ubuntu software (original)"orange icon" - installed apps blank screen.I had not realized "blue" icon software center was also installed.

The "temp fix" was closing the software center. Opened Terminal, and run
:~$ killall snap-store

- Relaunch Ubuntu Software; in some cases reboot before opening Ubuntu Software may be necessary!

**Solution** I found; "orange" icon Ubuntu Software (was) on faves list previous.(Removed from fav. list)

- Changed > Added "blue" icon software to faves. Ran :~$ killall snap-store (close terminal)

Next launch "blue" Software; immediately noticed notification of required update plugins.Updating took less then 30 seconds!After update as soon as software app opened; the menu's and all functionality had been updated and restored "Gnome Software" screens. Explore tab with categories, and installed tab correctly preview installed!Tested relaunch> quite> relaunch; all working flawless. Did not require any removal of either old or new software apps!