# Is the Snap Store replaced with Ubuntu Software? Or Why was Snap Store removed from my Ubuntu 20.04 installation?

Tags: 20.04, software-center, snap

**Update Note**: This question is different than [Has 'Ubuntu Software' been renamed to 'Snap Store'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252134/has-ubuntu-software-been-renamed-to-snap-store) because as I learned it seems that the Snap-Store has been renamed to Ubuntu Software -- the opposite of the other question.
The Ubuntu Software icon shows up but the actual command that runs is snap-store (see the answer posted to this question).

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 about 2 weeks ago (from 18.04).
I had the Snap Store in my installation and had ran it.
Today I went to run it and couldn't find it.  Then learned there is Ubuntu Software app which shows my Snaps in it.

Is Ubuntu Software a complete replacement for Snap Store?

I'm a developer and I deployed my Software via SnapCraft (https://snapcraft.io/cyapass)
I notice that my app shows up in Ubuntu Software:
[image: cyapass software]

So, does this mean I don't need the Snap Store any more?
Does Ubuntu Software include everything that is deployed to Snap.io?

Also, I notice that SnapCraft is installed but when I attempt to search for it, it doesn't show up.  Do you know why that might be?

[image: snapcraft]

[image: snap search fail]

**Inadvertently Removed?**

Was there some update that inadvertently removed the Snap Store?

**Update**

Here's another part that makes it a bit confusing.
If I look in "Ubuntu Software" app I see the following are installed:

[image: intalled pkgs]

Notice that you see the icon for Snap Store, but Ubuntu Software is not shown at all.

**Update 2**

Check this out.  When you run the command:

```
$ snap-store
```

You may also see a toast / pop-up that looks like the following:

[image: toast - ubuntu software]

Even though you started up snap-store it says that "Ubuntu Software is ready".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has 'Ubuntu Software' been renamed to 'Snap Store'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252134/has-ubuntu-software-been-renamed-to-snap-store)

Comment: I don't think so, because that one mentions that Ubuntu Software was removed and that they are separate things, but I'm not sure that is true now.  But I'm unsure.  Maybe they've now gone the opposite direction (Snap Store is renamed Ubuntu Software) because that's how it is on my system suddenly.

Comment: I've got both apps installed on 20.04 and they are two separate apps. To prove it the two different apps have two different icons in the Dash which are shown as images in the first sentence of the accepted answer to the linked duplicate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right after I posted, I thought about it and tried:

```
$ snap-store
```

When I ran that command, the Ubuntu Software app started on my machine.

So I suppose the answer is that Ubuntu Software is now the same thing as Snap Store.

Starting it from the command line is $ snap-store.

However, I see it as an icon as:

[image: ubuntu software icon]

That is a little confusing.  Probably just all part of ongoing changes.

**Update**

Also, notice that if I search for the Ubuntu Software item to see it in Ubuntu Software then I see the following (notice it shows that it is not installed) item which is similar to Ubuntu Software but is named Gnome Software.  This is all a bit confusing.

[image: Gnome Software]

I also found that we can run another command to get more information:

```
$ snap info snap-store
```

[image: snap info]