# I lost my software center

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, snap, gnome-software

I wanted to install snap-store, but got this error message:

```
error:unable to contact snap store
```

I decided to reinstall snapd, so I ran these commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge snapd
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

After that I lost my software center. Is there a way to bring it back? I tried:

```
sudo apt install software-center
```

but I got this error message:

```
E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has 'Ubuntu Software' been renamed to 'Snap Store'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252134/has-ubuntu-software-been-renamed-to-snap-store)

Answer (score 6):

Enter the command

```
sudo apt install snapd gnome-software gnome-software-plugin-snap
```