# No Application found in Ubuntu Software Center 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-center

I've recently noticed an issue with Ubuntu Software Center which I have tried to resolve following the answers provided in [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238069/ubuntu-software-not-loading-properly) without result and [this answer in particular](https://askubuntu.com/a/1289394/307670) which partially worked but didn't persist.

**The Issue**

After installing 20.04 I opened Ubuntu Software Center and installed a number of apps without any problem - one of which was Stacer which I will use as an example.

[image]

In `Show Applications` the app is clearly present and right clicking on the icon selecting `Show Details` provides the image above and it works perfectly well.

However, if I open Ubuntu Software Center and type in the search bar `stacer` it reports that no application is found:

[image]

Nor is it listed when selecting the `Installed` tab.

This is the setup for for Software and Updates.

[image]

There are other applications I have previously installed which are also now reported as `No Application found` such as gLabels, gscan2pdf and others.

Has something changed since I initially installed 20.04.1 and more importantly, how can I restore good order to the Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: I have seen a similar thing and have been trying to track down the cause 

Comment: @Matigo I tracked it down and have posted an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has 'Ubuntu Software' been renamed to 'Snap Store'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252134/has-ubuntu-software-been-renamed-to-snap-store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It boils down to an issue between the apt and snap versions of Ubuntu Software.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1252185/307670) from an [earlier question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1252137/307670) helped  to provide a solution.

**What I did**

In terminal:

```
snap remove snap-store  
sudo apt-get install gnome-software
```

followed by

```
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

That installed `Software` [image] as opposed to the large yellow icon previously associated with `Ubuntu Software` after which the "missing" packages were then correctly listed.

There are solutions to restore the old icon if I wish (not essential) and to reinstall snap-store which can apparently co-exist with the apt version

Comment: sudo apt install gnome-software

Answer (score 0):

In terminal:

snap remove snap-store

You need a

snap install snap-store

then

sudo apt-get install gnome-software

followed by

sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-snap