# snapd runtime environment update

Tags: 20.04, snap-store

After asking [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321026/no-application-found-in-ubuntu-software-center-20-04?noredirect=1#comment2250922_1321026) I found a solution.

However after applying the commands which effectively removed `snap-store` I then get a message indicating an application update to `core 16` the snapd runtime environment.

On selecting `Update All` a message appears `Unable to Install Updates: snap has no updates available`.

```
snap install snap-store has made no effect.
```

What must I do to correct this problem, clear the `Update` flag and ensure that any installed snaps are automatically updated?

[image]

Comment: Probably it has been upgraded in the background already. Try `snap refresh core`, it should give the same result.

Comment: @mook765 yes it returns "core" has no available updates but how to remove the message flag from Software?

Comment: Restart gnome software by using `killall gnome-software` may solve problem if it's a problem in gnome software or snap store.

Comment: @yangmandi Yes! that worked. Thank you. Post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @24601, Thx for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart gnome software by using `killall gnome-software` or `sudo killall gnome-software` command  solve the problem if it's a problem in gnome software or snap store.

Comment: there was no need for `sudo`