# Snap Store doesn't show categories

Tags: snap-store

I have install Ubuntu 20.04 on multiple machines and it has always shown the categories till now.  What is going on and how can I fix this.  I have tried everything posted on this site and none of it works.

Comment: Does [this question/answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321026/no-application-found-in-ubuntu-software-center-20-04) help?

Comment: At the time of my post there were 3 entries for this question.  So yes, I tried the solotions for each of those and they failed to work.  So instead of doing something constructive, I don't know like maybe actually helping someone out, you chose to be a smart ass.

Comment: A bit harsh, but @user535733 is right though. You gave us no information at all regarding your issue, so no one here knows how to help and will skip your question. As a new user you might want to take the [tour] first, and also refer to [ask] prior to asking.

Comment: I am sorry, I felt that user535733 was the one being harsh (I am not new to computers I have been software engineer since 1983), and I thought I was pretty clear on the issue, but I will restate it (now that I have a little more info).  If I install 20.04.2 on a clean drive the snap store doesn't list any categories, I can still search but the categories in browse are gone.  However if I upgrade from a previous version where the categories have always been there it appears to work fine.  It's only on a clean install that this is an issue.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved with the latest update, every machine I have with this issue is now working correctly so evidently the problem was with Ubuntu.

Thanks,