# What is the difference between "ubuntu software" and "software" centres?

Tags: software-center, snap

Why are there two software centres in Ubuntu 20.04? What happens if I install an app from both the software centres separately?

Comment: Difference primarily is they are different apps & present details differently.  Yes they can use different sources (eg. some use only standard sources enabled on your system), others can use different sources (ie. *deb* packages from your enabled sources, or snaps from a list), and some vary on the lists they use (and can add sources to your system if you select an app that isn't currently enabled or used on your system). Some may change your sources but only if you install a package that requires it but you won't get duplicates unless you select/cause it (and there are more than two stores)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has 'Ubuntu Software' been renamed to 'Snap Store'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252134/has-ubuntu-software-been-renamed-to-snap-store)

Answer (score 1):

"Software stores" are merely front-ends (GUI) for the actual commands that install stuff so no, you never "install an app from both the software centres separately", you install it from the repositories (.deb or snap or both if you want) regardless of the method or GUI tool.