# Two software manager?

Tags: software-center, icons, update-manager

Upon upgrading to 20.04, there are apparently two different Software managers. One of them doesn't even have a proper icon

[image]

One is called `Software`, the other `Ubuntu Software`. I guess this is not what expected?

Comment: It's not showing because your selected theme does **not** have a icon that it can show for that name. The issue should not have occurred if you were using the provided Ubuntu themes; but it's common for users to add additional themes & use them (*as well as apps/packages which can include additional software stores - hey I love Ubuntu MATE's Software Boutique*!); these can have minor but insignificant issues you don't need to worry about.

Comment: @guiverc, yet why two of them?

Comment: Multiple doesn't surprise me but I have limited facts. You can have a package installed as *deb* & also as *snap* meaning two of the same package can co-exist; as well you can have multiple *snap* versions installed, as well as *flatpak* etc so more than 2 is possible too. I have many as I've multiple DEs installed on my box; ie. I installed packages that caused many duplicates to co-exist on my box; but I don't know what you've installed, thus what to expect on your box.  *I don't know what your picture is showing as I can't tell what you're showing so I can't make use of that detail*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has 'Ubuntu Software' been renamed to 'Snap Store'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252134/has-ubuntu-software-been-renamed-to-snap-store)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Two software centers**

You have Gnome software center (`gnome-software-center`) that was already on your system, and has now been upgraded, and the Ubuntu Snap store, a Canonical customized software center installed as a snap, not existing in the the previous LTS release of Ubuntu.

*Resolution*: Keep both, or remove one of them: `sudo apt remove gnome-software` to remove Gnome Software, or `snap remove snap-store`  to remove Snap Store.

**Lacking icon**

The icon issue may be caused because you are using the Humanity icon theme, which remains in effect after the upgrade. The new default icon theme in 20.04, however, is Yaru. It contains a new icon for Ubuntu Software (the snap package), "ubuntusoftware.png", an icon not included in the Humanity icon theme.

*Resolution*: In case you removed Gnome Software, Snap Store will remain without an icon. Find `ubuntusoftware.png` of the Yaru theme installed under the  `/usr/share/themes/Yaru` directory and copy or symlink it it to `/usr/local/share/icons` (or `~/.local/share/icons`) for it to become available under your current theme. You may need to create these directories first. Alternatively, you may want to change to the Yaru theme.