# 22.04.03 LTS Problem

Tags: 22.04, lts

It is now 8/11/23 here where I am. About a week ago, my system upgraded to 22.04.3 LTS. After the reboot, I no longer have any cursors on the desktop, just a white square. I solved this problem by installing a 3rd party set of cursors. I also lost the Software update app. I now have to open a terminal and run SUDO APT-GET UPDATE and SUDO APT-GET UPGRADE as well as using the Synaptic Package Manager. My qBittourrent is gone as well. I have not found anywhere that the 22.04.3 LTS update has been released. I have searched for hours and have not found any help for these problems. I am unsure how to fix this problem.

Comment: Use sudo apt update && sudo apt install update-manager && sudo apt install qBittorrent. After this, you should be able to access the Software Update app and qBittorrent again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has 'Ubuntu Software' been renamed to 'Snap Store'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252134/has-ubuntu-software-been-renamed-to-snap-store)

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I have already gotten some of the functionality back. Unfortunately, I have not been able to get the default cursors or the ability to change the location of my Favorite bar back onto my desktop. This ability is NOT on the Appearance tab of Settings. I have gotten pretty much everything else restored. I hate the 3rd party cursors that I have to use, but still haven't been able to figure out how to restore the defaults yet.