# Snap updates sometimes working

Tags: updates

Sorry if this is a duplicate.
This site seems to do weird things when I post/ask a question.

Now and then when I boot I get a requestor saying that some programs need to be updated.

Whether I pick the "update all" or do them one at a time sometimes this happens.
(example picture)

[image]

What's going on?

Next boot can be that all things are up to date, other times, not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you could do to prevent this error message from occurring is to close Ubuntu Software and allow the package's software update in process to complete before continuing to update other snap packages.

An easier and less nerve-wracking way of solving this problem is to refuse multiple package update prompts in Ubuntu Software, close the Ubuntu Software app, and update all the snap packages that have pending updates together by running `sudo snap refresh` from the terminal. The `sudo snap refresh` command works every time without fail.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand either reply.
What do you mean "Close Ubuntu Software"?   That program?
How do I refuse multiple package update prompts?  Would it be better if I did sudo apt udpate sudo apt upgrade?
Ok, sorry that last bit is kind of dumb on my part.  You did explain it and I tried it.  Works better.

Comment: The confusing part seems to be "Close Ubuntu Software" because in Ubuntu 22.04 there are three different apps installed by default that are similar to Ubuntu Software - Ubuntu Software, GNOME Software and the Snap Store app. You can see images of their icons and an explanation of their differences in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1252137/).